# Shift cells left add blank column to the end of the table

Tags: excel

I have data among M8-V68, users are input their availability as 'Y' or 'N'. It includes 10 days in a row, the days are shifting everyday (by function =TODAY()) I need to shift the data provided by users as the days are shifting.

So, the idea is like following,

```
          02/11  03/11  04/11
Mark        Y      Y      N
Kate        N      Y      Y
```

When I open the document tomorrow, I would like to see following,

```
         03/11   04/11   05/11
Mark       Y       N
Kate       Y       Y
```

So, data for 02/11 is deleted and others are shifted. As I noted, dates are already shifting as I want, so all I want is data to shift left and the new column for upcoming date will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to VBA, this would do the trick:

```
Sub AddNewDate()
    Columns("M:M").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("V8").Value = Int(VBA.Now + 10)
    Range("V8").NumberFormat = "DD/MM"
End Sub
```

It will overwrite the formulas in your header eventually, which may or may not be okay with you.  If not, you can do this:

```
Range("M9:M69").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

I'm assuming your dates are in row 8.  If not, you will need to adjust accordingly.